# set table alias in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

how to set an alias name for eloquen's table ?
i tried

> protected $table = 'tableA as tblA';

but it will cause an error when calling create or insert. is there a way to do that ?

Comment: we really need more context, this is just a variable assignment...

Comment: `
class TableA extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tableA as tblA';
}
TableA::insert([id => 1, name => 'test');
`
error
`
Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as `ua` (`id`, `name`) values (?, ?)' at line 1 (SQL: insert into `tableA` as `tblA` (`id`, `name`) values (1, test))
`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're using 4.2 or 5 but it's petty much the same either way.

You can do **raw** queries in laravel which will let you alias tables. Try something like this:

```
  $table= DB::table('your_table_name AS alias')
           ->select('alias.id as id')
           ->get();
```